# I get duplicate entries with the attach method in Laravel 5. Not sure what the problem is

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pivot-table, lookup-tables

So I'm trying to attach id's with some meta data to a pivot table in Laravel 5.

For some reason, I get the two inserts where there should be one, and the wrong ID's being inserted the second time round.

I'm not sure if there is something I might be missing here.

This is the code:

```
$match_values = array(
                    'dataId' => $result->id,
                    'dataMetaId' => $the_meta->id
                );

                $result->campaignDataMeta()->attach($match_values, [
                    'meta_value' => $value
                ]);
```

The database structure consists of a main campaignData table for email campaigns, a campaignDataMeta table (id, timestamps, name) for email meta data names, and a lookup table campaignDataMatches (id, campaignDataId, campaignDataMetaId, meta_value).

In campaignDataMatches I get the campaignDataId value sometimes being inserted into the campaignDataMeta column.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. Which IDs? What's the DB structure? How do the relationship functions look like in the model? Otherwise, noone can help

Comment: @Tapha, could you provide more code context from this specific function? As well as the model classes?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

Apparently had to add the relevant ID (in this case the dataMetaId) within the attach parameter.

Like this:

```
$result->dataMeta()->attach([$data_meta_id => [
                    'meta_value' => $value
                ]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the database columns primary maybe the dataId and metaId are both primary.